# Set the transparency of a circle on a bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to set the transparency of a circle on a bitmap in C# .NET Winforms. I tried doing it using Graphics.DrawEllipse like this:

```
private void setCircleAlpha(int alpha, ref Bitmap b, ColumnVector2 pos, int diameter)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));

        g.FillEllipse(sb, pos.X, pos.Y, diameter, diameter);
    }
```

but that does not do what I want as it **draws** a transparent circle over the image instead of setting the transparency of that circle.

I have resorted to using this extremely slow code:

```
private void setCircleAlpha(int alpha, ref Bitmap b, ColumnVector2 pos, int diameter)
    {
        //Calculate the square root of the radius
        float radius = diameter / 2;
        float sqRadius = radius * radius;

        //Calculate the centre of the circle
        ColumnVector2 centre = pos + new ColumnVector2(radius, radius);

        for (int x = (int)pos.X; x < pos.X + diameter; x++)
        {
            for (int y = (int)pos.Y; y < pos.Y + diameter; y++)
            {
                //Calculate the distance between the centre of the circle and the point being tested
                ColumnVector2 vec = new ColumnVector2(x, y) - centre;

                //If the distance between a point and the centre of a circle is less than the radius of that circle then that point is in the circle.

                //Calculate distance using pythagoras (a^2 + b^2 = c^2)
                //Square both the distance and radius to eliminate need for square root
                float sqDist = (vec.X * vec.X) + (vec.Y * vec.Y);

                if (sqDist < sqRadius)
                {
                    b.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(alpha, b.GetPixel(x, y)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is: *Is there a better/faster way to do this?*

Please note that I'm not asking for faster circle generation algorithms, rather I am asking for alternative graphics options.

Comment: Use the 1st snippet.  You are looking for the Graphics.CompositingMode property, set it to SourceCopy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Hans Passant's comment I got this working:

```
private void setCircleAlpha(int alpha, ref Bitmap b, ColumnVector2 pos, int diameter)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, 0, 0, 0));

        g.FillEllipse(sb, pos.X, pos.Y, diameter, diameter);
    }
```

Comment: where the alpha parameter is used?

Comment: @ Mehrzad : `Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)` this is a transparent black. The 1st 0 is alpha.

Comment: Oops - I forgot to edit the code to include alpha! I'll correct that now.